# Finding the exact length of the curve: $y^2=16(x+3)^3,\;\;0\le x\le3,\;\;y\gt0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, curves, arc-length

I need to find the exact length of the curve in the title. I'm mostly confused about how to set up y. Would y equal the square root of the other side? I've tried that and my answer comes out wrong.

Here's what I'm trying:
$$y=\sqrt{16(x+3)^3}$$
And then I take the derivative of that and put it into the arc length formula and solve, but I don't get the value that my book gets.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What value do you get and what value does your book get? Sometimes the book answer is incorrect.

Comment: If I am right the arc length should be $$\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{109+36x}\,dx = \frac{217\sqrt{217}-109\sqrt{109}}{54}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It was the book that was wrong! Somehow, somewhere, they got 105 instead of 109... I was correct in the first place. Must have been a typo. It was driving me crazy trying to find where I was wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would approach the problem by parametrizing the curve as follows:
$$ x = t^2 - 3    \qquad \qquad y = 4t^3  \qquad (\sqrt{3} \leq t \leq \sqrt{6})$$

In which case we see that:
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 2t \qquad \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} = 12t^2 $$

and so the arc length is expressed as:
\begin{align*}
L &= \int_C \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2} \, dt \\
&= \int_\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{6} \sqrt{(2t)^2 + (12t^2)^2} \, dt \\ 
&= \int_\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{6} \sqrt{144t^4 + 4t^2} \, dt \\
&= \int_\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{6} 2t \sqrt{36t^2 + 1} \, dt \\
&= \int_3^6 \sqrt{36u + 1} \, du \\
&= \left[ \frac{1}{54}(36u+1)^\frac{3}{2} \right]_3^6 \\
&= \frac{217\sqrt{217} - 109\sqrt{109}}{54} \approx 38.1225
\end{align*}

---

Though I come to see that the problem also works out nicely in Cartesian coordinates rather than parametric coordinates:
\begin{align*}
y &= 4(x+3)^{3/2} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= 6\sqrt{x+3}
\end{align*}
So the arc length is expressed as:
\begin{align*}
L &= \int_C \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^3 \sqrt{1 + 36(3+x)} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^3 \sqrt{36x + 109} \, dx \\
&= \left[\frac{1}{54}(36x+109)^\frac{3}{2} \right]_0^3 \\
&= \frac{217\sqrt{217} - 109\sqrt{109}}{54} \approx 38.1225
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You want: $$
\begin{align}
\int_0^3\sqrt{1+\left(y'\right)^2}\,dx
\end{align}$$
And with implicit differentiation you have that: $$2yy'=48(x+3)^2$$
$$y'=\frac{24(x+3)^2}{y}$$
So you want:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^3\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{24(x+3)^2}{y}\right)^2}\,dx
&=\int_0^3\sqrt{1+\frac{24^2(x+3)^4}{y^2}}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^3\sqrt{1+\frac{24^2(x+3)^4}{16(x+3)^3}}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^3\sqrt{1+36(x+3)}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^3\sqrt{36x+109}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{36}\int_{109}^{217}\sqrt{u}\,du\\
\end{align}$$
which should be easy to finish.